# Memory management help needed- static class variables Objective C

Tags: objective-c, ios, memory-management, static-variables

I want to use a static class variable to maintain state of a Playlist object which will be shared between multiple classes in my app.

I make a call to getPlaylist in my AppDelegate, so that invokes my initialize class method and sets up the MSMutableArray.

However when I invoke addItemToPlaylist, the content variable is no longer the static instance of NSMutableArray. Instead it points to a totally different address in memory- a different address each time I debug.

Am I doing anything obviously wrong? Thanks in advance.

```
#import "Playlist.h"
static NSMutableArray *content;

@implementation Playlist

+ (void)initialize
{
    content = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:10]; 
}

+ (NSMutableArray *)getPlaylist
{
    if ([content count] == 0)
        return nil;

    return content;
}  

+ (void)addItemToPlaylist:(PlaylistTrack *)track; 
{
    [content addObject:track];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity]` returns an auto-released object (there should be a complaint at runtime about there being no current auto-release pool).

Use `[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity]` instead and add a class method to release it when done.

EDIT: Cheers @Lvsti.

Comment: `[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:]` to be exact

Comment: Amazing stuff- thanks for the quick reply. I'm not seeing a runtime complaint about the autorelease pool, should that appear in the console window? Thanks again.

Comment: Yeah I have seen the message when using class methods as they are outside of the run loop (generally).  It's not important if you don't see them but they might have given you a clue I guess.

Comment: There IS an autorelease poool. It's created for you in the main method in main.m ;)

Comment: @JavierSoto Agreed, but I have seen runtime warnings from class methods if I don't create my own (temporary) autoreleasepool.

Comment: Can you give an example? That only would happen when you work creating an NSThread.

Comment: @JavierSoto No, I have seen it with a single-threaded App (the one I am developing at the moment).  I have several utility classes that I initialise from my App Controller's `initialize` method (by calling class-level methods in the utility classes).  If I don't put an `@autoreleasepool` around some methods then I get a warning message on the console.